# HTML5 video not always autoplaying on iPhones

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video, safari

I am trying to autoplay a looping video using the following code;

`<video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="/bg.jpg" id="vid">
        <source src="/bg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="/bg.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>`

Most of the time this works but very occasionally on an iPhone7 it fails to autoplay the video and instead displays the play icon. It can happen on WiFi or mobile data but never happens on desktop or Android. No other tabs are open in Safari.

Is this likely to be a bandwidth issue, a code issue or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

hope this link will help you:(ios has policies for video autoplay )

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

Comment: please post your answer, then references. sometimes, this page may removed. at that time this is useless.

Comment: Thanks for the useful link - sadly if the video refused to play at all I'd agree it was because of it going against policy but it only fails intermittently.